# Repeated data in a XML

Tags: xml, xquery

How can I get the () data which it's not repeated in a variable.

I use this function:

```
.
.
.
let $person:= $hopital1/persona
    for $seq in (1 to count($derechohabiente))
    return
       $person[$seq]
       [not(xf:is-node-secuence-equal(.,$person[position() < $seq])) ]

declare function xf:is-node-secuence-equal ( $node as node()? , $seq as node()*)  as xs:boolean {
    some $nodeInSeq in $seq satisfies fn:deep-equal($nodeInSeq/name, $node/ns0:name)
};
.
.
.
```

This is the XML example, I just want to get Joseph's information, but I get only the data repeated

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hospital>
    <person>
        <idee>1902</idee>
        <name>Joseph</name>
        <age>60</age>
        <room>4</room>
        <service>false</service>        
    </person>
    <person>
        <idee>3246</idee>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <room>0</room>
        <service>false</service>        
    </person>
    <person>
        <idee>3246</idee>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <room>0</room>
        <service>true</service>        
    </person>
    <person>
        <idee>3246</idee>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <room>5</room>
        <service>true</service>        
    </person>
</hospital>
```

**Update from comments**

> I want to  get the data which is not
>   repeated; if you see the XML example,
>   this is the result I'd like to get:
>
> ```
> <hospital>
>     <person>
>         <idee>1902</idee>
>         <name>Joseph</name>
>         <age>60</age>
>         <room>4</room>
>         <service>false</service>
>     </person>
> </hospital>
> ```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Alejandro: 
Sorry for question.
I wanna get the data which is not repeated; if you see the XML example, this is the result i'd like to get:
<hospital>
    <person>
        <idee>1902</idee>
        <name>Joseph</name>
        <age>60</age>
        <room>4</room>
        <service>false</service>        
    </person>
</hospital>
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Two XQuery expressions:

```
/hospital/person[not(name = (../person except .)/name)]
```

And

```
/hospital/person[not(index-of(../person/name,name)[2])]
```