# Get repeated data in a XML

Tags: xml, xquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeated data in a XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398216/repeated-data-in-a-xml)

How can i get the () data which it's not repeated in a variable.

I use this function:

```
.
.
.
let $person:= $hopital1/persona
    for $seq in (1 to count($derechohabiente))
    return
       $person[$seq]
       [not(xf:is-node-secuence-equal(.,$derechohabiente[position() < $seq])) ]

declare function xf:is-node-secuence-equal ( $node as node()? , $seq as node()*)  as xs:boolean {
    some $nodeInSeq in $seq satisfies fn:deep-equal($nodeInSeq/name, $node/ns0:name)
};
.
.
.
```

This is the XML example, i just wanna get Joseph's information, but i get only the data not repeated and one person repeated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hospital>
    <person>
        <idee>1902</idee>
        <name>Joseph</name>
        <age>60</age>
        <room>4</room>
        <service>false</service>        
    </person>
    <person>
        <idee>3246</idee>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <room>0</room>
        <service>false</service>        
    </person>
    <person>
        <idee>3246</idee>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <room>0</room>
        <service>true</service>        
    </person>
    <person>
        <idee>3246</idee>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <room>5</room>
        <service>true</service>        
    </person>
</hospital>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's difficult to help troubleshoot.  Your XML and XQuery don't line up at all.  For example, what do $hopital1 and $derechohabiente refer to?  Also, in XQuery, function declarations have to come before the main expression, so the fact that your function declaration comes after the "let..." expression would lead to problems.